# How to check really width with "auto" value on css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a loop:

```
var takediv = document.getElementById('eye');
for(var i=0; i<categories.length; i++){
   takediv.innerHTML +=^
       '<img alt="'+(categories.length-i)+'" '+
       'onclick="changef(this.alt)" '+
       'src="mobile/img/pic/'+loc+"/mini/"+categories[categories.length-i-1][0]+'" '+
       'style="cursor: pointer;"/>';
}
```

All images are having this css:

> height: 80px;
>   width: auto;

And finally after loop I need to give the div this css

> document.getElementById('eye').style.width

which will be sum of all inner img widhts

It is my first post here so sorry for mistakes.
Please help, and thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use several approaches, for example `getBoundingClientRect()` which returns absolute values for position and width/height:

```
var width = document.getElementById('eye').getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

Just note it does not include border or padding, only the inner box.

Then there is `getComputedStyle()` - this will return a string suffixed with "px" so we also need to parse it using `parseInt()`:

```
var width = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document
                .getElementById('eye'))
                .getPropertyValue("width"), 10);
```

Both returns size in pixels.

And as in @Rudi's answer, there is `offsetWidth`, and also `clientWidth`. This won't include margin.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
var width = document.getElementById('eye').offsetWidth;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but it doesn't working.
It return for img value 10 (i dont know why)

Comment: Nice, glad I could help.